# Magento logout button vanishes on Order tracking page

Tags: magento, layout, magento-1.7

Login/Logout links in top.links show everywhere except for the standard order tracking page of Magento. I've replaced the customer.xml with the default but it doesn't fix the issue. Neither the login nor the logout link shows up in on that page. All the other links are showing fine. I wasn't able to find a fix for this issue. Anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its difficult in your customized setup so i just try to get you in the right direction:

Fetch your current layout handles, maybe you add this line into the controller or any active piece of code, to grab the handles active for your page:

```
Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

Check every active layout-handle in your layout-xml-files, maybe the link gets removed
If its not removed, it maybe is not added at all.

Way to remove via layout-xml-file:

```
<reference name="top.links">
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
                <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl" />
            </action>
</reference>
```

Way to add via layout-xml-file:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
  <label>Log In</label>
  <url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>
  <title>Log In</title>
  <prepare/>
  <urlParams/>
  <position>100</position>
</action>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. removeLinkByUrl is not found in any of the xml files! So  its not removed. And I know its being added in customer.xml under the block top.links, any other take on this?

Comment: have you debugged the active layout handles... to check wether the link is added in the correct handle?

Comment: Its in the customer_logged_in and customer_logged_out handles so it should show up in all the pages, whether the customer is logged in or not. And yes, I debugged.